# First integral & uniqueness of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Assume $x'=f(x)$ has a first integral $G(x)$. If the set $\{x\in\mathbb R: G(x)=G(x_0)\}$is bounded, why does the unique solution of $\cases{x'=f(x) & \cr x(0)=x_0}$ exist ?

If $G$ is the first integral of $x$ then it has the property that it is constant along $x$, i.e. $G(x(t))=constant$

(This is not a homework, we've written this theorem without proof, and googling didn't help, Is there another name for the first integral.)

Answer (score 1):

By the theorem of leaving compact: if the maximal solution is defined on the interval $[t_0,T)$, then mutually exclusively

either

1) $T=+\infty$

or

2) For every compact set $K$ there exists a point $t\in  [t_0,T)$ such that $x(t)\not\in K$.

Similarly for left boundary of the maximal solution.

In your case you know that the solution does not leave the compact $\{G(x)=G(x_0)\}$ (level set of a continuous function is closed, plus it is bounded by hypothesis), therefore the solution is defined for all time $t$.

Comment: So, for all time means it is unique ?

Comment: @OBDA no, you will need some other argument to prove uniqueness. If, for example, $f$ is a Lipschitz function, then you have uniqueness.